# Windows 8 Hyper-V - Development VM - VirtualBox better?

Tags: virtualbox, hyper-v

I would like to know how you use hyper-v and work inside your VM.

I am developer, and used to working with VM for my development environments.
Until now, I was working with VirtualBox.
Since I have moved to Windows 8, I wanted to try hyper-v but the experience is not as good as what I was accustomed with VirtualBox

For instance, I cannot work in full screen with hyper-v console. 
So I use Remote Desktop Connection as I read on many blogs.
But RDC graphics rendering is slow and working in Visual Studio or Blend with it, is not really a pleasure.
For now, I decided to get back to VirtualBox.

How do you access your VM? Is hyper-v really foreseen for that kind of VM or is it more for server like VM that you access only for configuration and/or administration tasks?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

in order to work in full screen with hyper-v console, I adjusted the screen resolution of the guest VM within the VM, by right click the desktop. and it works fun, hotkeys are similar to that of RDC. like ctrl+alt+delete become ctrl+alt+end